# Xen Windows Guest spawn doesn't spawn a vnc display

Tags: xen, vnc

I'm using this HVM File to create a new guest

```
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen-3.2-1/boot/hvmloader"
builder='hvm'
memory = 4096

# Should be at least 2KB per MB of domain memory, plus a few MB per vcpu.
shadow_memory = 64
name = "hessel-windows2008"
vif = [ 'ip=188.40.xx.xx,mac=00:16:3E:C1:8F:CE' ]

acpi = 1
apic = 1
disk = [ 'file:/home/xen/disks/hessel/win2008/win2008.img,hda,w', 'file:/home/xen/isopool/win2008_32.iso,hdc:cdrom,r' ]

device_model = '/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm'

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# boot on floppy (a), hard disk (c) or CD-ROM (d) 
# default: hard disk, cd-rom, floppy
boot="dc"

sdl=0
vnc=1
vncdisplay=1 
vnclisten="0.0.0.0"
vncconsole=1
vncpasswd='howtoforge'

stdvga=0 

serial='pty'
usbdevice='tablet'
```

The guest is created without an error. But no vnc display is created.
Any ideas, how to fix that?

```
prometheus:~# netstat -ant

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:615           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0    232 188.40.xx.xx:8080      195.36.75.26:54032      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 188.40.xx.xx:8080      195.36.75.26:53085      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line I'm using for mine looks like this:

```
vfb=['type=vnc,vncdisplay=2,vnclisten=192.168.100.10,vncpasswd=howtoforge']
```

Which causes the port to listen. But then, I'm using a slightly older version of Xen than you are.

Comment: Already tried that, but it seems vnc doesn't start because it's trying to bind to the xen bridge witch doesn't exist, because I have to use a routed network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `vncunused = 0` in your config.  That's the only real difference between your setup and the one we're running here.

Comment: do you use a bridged xen setup?

Comment: That's not relevant to the problem at hand.